# How can I calculate this integral?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

How can I find the answer of this integral
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{(x^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{e^{mx}-1}\, dx$$
where $m>0$.

Comment: We need more information.  Why do you think there is a closed form?

Comment: A start might be the generating function for the Bernoulli numbers.